# retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices does not return devices that currently connected to the system

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

i want to collect data about the bluetooth devices the user is sometimes connect to.

i'm using: "retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices"
with service: 180A - device info

```
 NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180A"]];
_connectedPeripherals = [_btManager retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:services];
```

but when the system connecting to android devices or even sometimes macbook the list return empty

Comment: Why do you believe the device is currently BLE connected to the iPhone? How have you verified that?

Comment: Because I connected to it through the settings of the system

Comment: The Settings app's Bluetooth panel doesn't allow you to make BLE connections. It allows you to make Bluetooth EDR (i.e. Bluetooth audio) connections. Those are a completely different thing. How are you connecting to a Macbook through Settings?

Comment: sow, I will rephrase: is there any way to get the list if current connected bluetooth devices?

Comment: You can get a list of connected bluetooth (BLE, not BDR) devices that provide a particular service (just pass the UUIDs of the services you require). You cannot get a list of all connected devices without knowing what service you want. Many devices do not provide the Device Info service. If you don't have a service in mind, what are you going to do with the list? What's the goal?